# Зачем нужен super(), если можно и без него?

Tags: python-3.x

Я начинаю изучать классы и столкнулся с super.

```
class B:
    def c(self):
        print(1)

class A(B):

    def __init__(self):
        A.c(self)
A()
```

Так код выведет 1, но если использовать super:

```
class B:
    def c(self):
        print(1)

class A(B):

    def __init__(self):
        super().c()
A()
```

тоже 1, у меня вопрос зачем нужен super?

Comment: super() – это встроенная функция языка Python. Она возвращает прокси-объект, который делегирует вызовы методов классу-родителю (или собрату) текущего класса (или класса на выбор, если он указан, как параметр).

Основное ее применение и польза – получения доступа из класса наследника к методам класса-родителя в том случае, если наследник переопределил эти методы.
[источник](https://tirinox.ru/super-python/)

Comment: Если совсем кратко, то вы забываете учитывать множественное наследование и вылезающие из-за этого проблемы с порядком разрешения методов (mro)

Comment: просто посмотри это видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61UuKJRl2m0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

потому что вы записали код, в котором особенности `super()` никак не используются

Вот какой код вам надо было бы привести:

```
class B:
    def c(self):
        print("B::c")

class A(B):
    def c(self):
        print("A::c")

    def __init__(self):
        A.c(self) # вызывается родной метод c

A()

class D:
    def c(self):
        print("D::c")

class C(D):
    def c(self):
        print("C::c")

    def __init__(self):
        super().c() # вызывается метод c родительского класса D

C()
```

В первом случае через `A.c(self)` вы вызовете родной метод, а через `super().c()` _ родительский

У вас же чаще всего будут ситуации, когда и у родителя и у потомка есть один и тот же метод и какой именно вызвать - родной (дочерний) или родительский как раз и будет решаться через вызов `super()`

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Основной смысл в том, чтобы класс-наследник мог вызывать какие-то методы класса-родителя, при этом *не указывая название класса-родителя в явном виде*. Это удобно на тот случай, если вы захотите поменять название класса-родителя или просто унаследоваться от другого класса. В этом случае вы просто поменяете родителя в заголовке класса и вам не надо будет бегать по коду искать все места использования родителя в потомке, чтобы поменять их. Если у вас используется `super()`, то совершенно не важно, как называется класс-родитель, к нему доступ будет точно так же через `super()` и ничего в коде не нужно будет менять.